# MockMVC tests how can I verify the answer

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito, mockmvc

I have a following test method in mockMVC

I need to improve the tests to make sense.
at the moment tests are not testing, how to improve to test? just add verification of data compliance? how to add it? What could be the example of data validation verification?
how to test if UUID agrees?

how to improve these tests?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
@Test
public void createUser() throws Exception {
    User user = userRepository.save(new User("testname", "testemail", 10));
    String userJson = toJson(user);

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/user/add/")
            .contentType(contentType)
            .content(userJson))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void getUserById() throws Exception {
    User user = userRepository.save(new User("testname", "testemail", 10));   
    mockMvc.perform(get("/user/" + user.getId()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(user.getId())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username", is(user.getUsername())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.age", is(user.getAge())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.emailAddress", is(user.getEmailAddress())));
}
```

You can check whole test class in my [github repo](https://github.com/xjahic/tinder2/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/vanillahoney/tinder2/user/rest/UserRestApiTest.java)

Hopefully this will help you

Comment: I have a bug   java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.version"

 at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:290)
 at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$0(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:179)

Comment: i added .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version", is("0.1")))
                 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is(accountCreatedDTO .getEmail())))
                 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(accountCreatedDTO .getName())))

Comment: Try to print returned json and see what's going on

Comment: at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)

Comment: Caused by: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected End Of File position 63963: null
 at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserMemory.readString(JSONParserMemory.java:122)
 at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readObject(JSONParserBase.java:526)
 at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readMain(JSONParserBase.java:403)
 at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readObject(JSONParserBase.java:546)
 at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readMain(JSONParserBase.java:403)
 at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readObject(JSONParserBase.java:546)

Comment: I can't help you like this it is impossible. This is one of the moments when you have to help yourself, that's how you learn

Comment: *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844